# In a unipole eddy current brake, is it possible to create a perpendicular attraction/repulsion force between the magnetic pole and the metal plate?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

...or do the magnetic fields created from the induced, circular currents according to Ampere's circuital law at the leading vs. trailing edge of the magnet always exactly cancel out?

I'm particularly curious regarding the case of supposed "dynamically-responsive" eddy current brakes used on the spools of fishing reels (!!).

In these, the banks of magnets on the brake "shoe" are often mounted on a spring-loaded pivot-arm - with the idea that the shoe should be pulled closer to the rotating, aluminium spool (the medium in which eddy currents are induced) as it spins faster (Left hand image)

As the spool rotation slows, the small spring is purported to pull one end of the pivoting brake shoe (and associated magnets) away from the aluminium surface.

However, I can't see a mechanism for this unless there is a way to create asymetric attraction and repulsion forces at the leading vs. trailing edge of the bank of magnets.

The overall braking force is controlled by how far inside the interior of the spool drum the bank of magnets is projected (right hand image).

[image: Banks of magnets which, in use, sit inside the rotating drum of the reel's spool]